# Google Chrome crashes now after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, 16.10

I have seen this issue on a number of sites but seems no one has an answer to it.  After upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 Chrome and all Google services crashes.  This seems to only happen on an upgrade and not on fresh installs.  I have reinstalled chrome with no luck.  Also based on a suggestion I cleared the cache and recreated the profile but did not help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Based on a suggestion below I ran this in the terminal here are the results:

```
 google-chrome
```

[24829:24861:1027/230234:ERROR:nss_util.cc(809)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
[24829:24829:1027/230234:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(13)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
[24829:24829:1027/230236:ERROR:display_info_provider_aura.cc(31)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::DisplayInfoProviderAura::UpdateDisplayUnitInfoForPlatform(const display::Display &, extensions::api::system_display::DisplayUnitInfo *)
[1,1472897280:03:02:40.977754] Native Client module will be loaded at base address 0x00007d2f00000000
--2016-10-27 23:06:40--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 216.58.218.238
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|216.58.218.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/3’

```
 0KCrash dump id:  86e72d0700000000 
                                                  2.03M=0s
```

2016-10-27 23:06:40 (2.03 MB/s) - ‘/dev/fd/3’ saved [16]

Segmentation fault

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to latest 16.04 updates. However I use firefox and am not sure if it is related to your issue

Comment: it seems the problem is only with Chrome.  My fresh install system is having the same issue.  Chromium is working without any issues.

Comment: To help diagnose the issue, try running chrome by opening a terminal window and typing `chrome` or `google-chrome` (I forget which it is). Then when it crashes, there should hopefully be some helpful error messages visible in the terminal window.

Comment: I ran chrome in terminal and posted the results above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in Chrome 54 and not Ubuntu. (16.10 was released at October 20th and Chrome 64 October 21st) I found the previous release here http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php, installed it; translate seems to work again, I'll see if it crashes.